# How to connect an ontology document to database

Tags: ontology, protege4

I was try to make an ontology even though haven't finish till now. I used protege for that. I'm used Ontology document for database knowledge representation. actually now i still confused how to linking or connecting my ontology document to database for get the data, because in ontology document i have only knowledge representation not data. if you have advice or solution please tell me, thank you so much.

Comment: Its difficult to understand what your actual question is. Could you provide some more information?
Any technologies you have used already? What is your ontology document? Do you want to load your ontology into a database like a Triplestore?

Comment: exactly i want to get the data from database for instance in owl document, but  i don't know how to do this. I am using Apache Solr 5.4 its use for Search engine machine, Postgree database and Protege to create ontology